# Class of Fourier Multipliers with $L^2$-Boundedness is Equal to $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $M_p$ be the class of Fourier multipliers with $L^2$-Boundedness, i.e.

$M_p := \{ m:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ | \ m \ \text{ is measurable}, \ \exists \ C>0 \ \text{such that}  \ ||T_m f||_p \leq C||f||_p  \ \forall f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)  \} $,

where $T_m = \mathcal{F}^{-1} [m \hat{f}] $ is a Fourier Multiplier, $\mathscr{S}$ is the Schwartz class of functions, and $||\cdot||_p$ is the $L^p$-Norm.

We are asked to prove that $M_2 = L^\infty$.

It is easy to prove that $L^\infty \subseteq M_2 $. For $m \in L^\infty$, and $f \in \mathscr{S}$, $||T_m f||_2 = || \mathcal{F}[T_m f] ||_2 = ||m \hat{f}||_2 \leq ||m||_\infty ||\hat{f}||_2 = ||m||_\infty ||f||_2 $.

Here, we have simply used Holder's Inequality and the equivalence of $L^2$-Norms under Fourier Transformation.

I am however having trouble proving the inverse, $M_2 \subseteq L^\infty $.

We let $m \in M_2$. Then we want to show that $\exists ||m||_\infty<\infty$.

We know that there exists a constant $C>0$, such that, for all $f \in \mathscr{S}$, $||T_m f ||_2 = ||m \hat{f}||_2 \leq C||f||_2 $.

It is easy to show that, if $m$ is a constant function, then $||m||_\infty \leq C $, however I cannot generalise this result to just measurable functions.

Any hints/sources are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If $\mu( |m|> a) > 0$ then let $W$ be a set of non-zero finite measure where $|m(x)|>a$, we have $\| m 1_W\|_2 \ge a \|1_W\|_2$. Thus the boudedness of $T_m$ implies that $\mu(|m|>a)=0$ for $a$ large enough, ie. $m\in L^\infty$.

Comment: Am I supposed to use $W$ in the following way? $||T_m f||_2 = ||m \hat{f}||_2 \geq ||m|_{W} \hat{f} ||_2 > a||f||_{L^2(W)}$.
I don't think this will actually help us, as it might be the case that $W$ becomes small as we take $a$ large....

Comment: Ah, now I see. We let $f = 1_W$. Of course. Thank you very much

Comment: You mean $\hat{f}=1_W$

Comment: Yes. Realised that when I tried to write it out. Thanks!